# List empty outside function - Python

Tags: python, list, function

I am trying to copy the lines of a text file into a list in one function, and then print the contents of that list in a 2nd function.
If I put the print statement in the first function it outputs the correct list, but if I try to print with the 2nd function it outputs an empty list.

How can I pass the list from my 1st function to my 2nd function?

My current code:

````py
def selectfile():
    userselect = input("Please type the filename, for an example you can type: numbers.txt or 10lines.txt: ")
    file = open(userselect, "r") #  grabs the user input from above and opens the selected file
    return file # puts the value into selectfile func


def TxttoList():  # starts the paste function
    file = selectfile()  # grabs the info from the function above
    lines = file.readlines()[1:]  # starts loading in the content line by line
    newlist = []  # declares my list
    for line in lines:  # loops through each line
        content = line.strip().split("\t")  # uses tab as separator
        newlist.append(content)  # adds the lines to the list
 #  print(newlist) //Lists prints as expected here if i remove the #, but I need the list in the function below. 
    return newlist


def TopScore():  # This is where I need the list I created above
    newlist = TxttoList() 
    print(newlist)  

TxttoList()  # starts the program ```
````

The result I expected:

> [Peter, 22] [hans, 11] [lars, 20] [flemming, 21] [dorte, 19] [bo, 11]

The result I received:

> 

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you calling the function TopScore() or TxttoList()? It may be that you are calling the latter resulting in the non-printing of the data

Comment: Solved thanks to Lior Cohen and Aaron Pereira! I simply forgot to actually call my function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling TxttoList() which indeed does not print.
Didn’t you mean to call TopScore() in the last line?

Comment: I'm an absolute idiot, it was really that simple haha.

Thank you very much, everything is now working as expected :-)